# How to send and receive hex or binary numbers via BLE UART?

Tags: nrf51

I am trying to send hex or binary numbers through BLE UART, but it is taking only char value which is converted into ASCII value.

I am using Adafruit's Bluefruit micro device and Bluefruit LE apps.

https://github.com/adafruit/Bluefruit_LE_Connect_Android
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BluefruitLE_nRF51

```
Serial.print(F("[Recv] "));
Serial.println(ble.buffer);
BluetoothData=ble.buffer[0];
Serial.println(BluetoothData);
```

[image]

In the UART box I want to type only a hex number and receive it in the Ble.buffer of the Arduino only.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your actual code, and explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is just a pattern of 0s and 1s, and can therefore be represented in binary, hex, octal, or decimal. The interpretation is entirely up to you in your code.

Comment: Representation is ok becoz it is possible only after receiving . i am asking about that if i type 0x01 on BLE apps than what value receive by uart.

Answer (score 0):

The hex button toggle switch will show what the value of your characters are in hex. find the character that matches the value you want to send and use that. if you type the string 0x01 the app will send 0x30 0x78 0x30 0x31 0x0A. Since it trys to convert your characters to hex.

this table is pretty handy showing what characters are represented by which hex numbers http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html.

unfortunately the character representing 0x01 is pretty difficult to type.

You can work around this issue by using the toInt() function in Arduino if you send the number 1 as a character the toInt() function will convert it to an int with value of 1. The hex equivalent is 0x01.

Answer (score 0):

Following code changes have been made to send the values in hex as input from user

1. replace the utf-8 conversion

value = message.getBytes("UTF-8");

by hex

int len = message.length();
byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(message.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
            + Character.digit(message.charAt(i+1), 16));
}
value=data;

2. suppress the exception headlining for UnsupportedEncodingException
   otherwise it throws a compile time error  UnsupportedEncodingException

Result examples :

3F ( hex ) results in ? ( ascii )
63 results in c

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about data representation. The value you are entering is a string, a sequence of characters, e.g. 0x42. The string can be parsed and converted to binary form either on the transmitting or receiving side.

The string must first be checked that it is valid. In this case a valid hex or decimal number. There are conversion functions that do both at the same time. The standard string function [strtol](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaf8ce3b8dae3d45c34c3b172de503f7b3)() is perfect for the job. With zero as base argument it will parse both hex, oct and dec number formats.

```
// Receive string 
char buf[BUF_MAX];
...
// Convert string to number
char* bp;
long value = strtol(buf, &bp, 0);
bool valid = (*bp == 0);
```

There is also an unsigned variant, [strtoul](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#gaea44aa48bda8261f794dcb2d1e7ab2b2).